# Error: listen EACCES IP:80 with ExpressJS and PM2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, adonis.js

I want host my ExpressJS (AdonisJS) application on PM2.

But, 80 port is not authorize less than 1024.

I want add HOST URL and PORT.

```
Error: listen EACCES IP:80
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1024:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1046:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1334:19)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1392:12)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1501:7)
at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:97:10)
```

Comment: Why do you use port 80 specifically? Why not 3000 for example?

Comment: I want use 80 port because I want my application is accessible from URL without port...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried sudo pm2 appname? You need sudo access for port 80

Comment: Yes I know but it is a user not sudoers... And I don't want he can sudo...

Comment: Then create a reverse proxy with node.js in pm2 in port 80 using sudo and then host your app on a different port, it is easy i can help you.